# Are transaction comments public?

Tags: transactions

Can other people see the message attached to the bitcoin transaction? Or is it only for receiver/sender to be seen?

Comment: What kind of comment are you talking about? What software or website? The answer is most likely no, as transactions themselves don't have a comment field.

Comment: Are you talking about the `comment` field in JSON RPC? `sendtoaddress "address" amount ( "comment" "comment_to" subtractfeefromamount replaceable conf_target "estimate_mode")`

Comment: Yes, comment field in JSON RPC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments that you add to transactions are for your wallet only. No one else will see them as transactions do not have anywhere to have comments. Comments on public blockchain explorers (such as tags on blockchain.info) will only appear on those websites as they are comments specific to those websites. They are not part of the transaction itself.